# Optimal way to add an element in k-th position of list of size n if k<n

Tags: python-3.x, list, optimization

I know it's possible to add an element inside a list **AND NOT AS THE FIRST ELEMENT NOR THE LAST** by redefining the list and adding three lists:

```
# I want to add 5 into [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,0] between the 4 and the 6
A=[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,0]
A=[1,2,3,4]+[5]+[6,7,8,9,0]
```

but I think this isn't optimal, since I'm creating three lists and re-defining a variable. Someone could show me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insert method of the list mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
L = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,0]
L.insert(4,5)
```

This is the optimized way of python, if you need more optimized insertion operation perhaps use some other data structure depending upon your need.